# How can I get back the attachment using the attachment_id received from Facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm developing a chatbot using the Facebook API. I sent an image successfully using the example provided in the Facebook API documentation, and it returned an attachment_id as expected. I also was able to use that ID in one or more messages without problems.

I'm wondering if there is something like a CRUD for the attachments. Is there?

How can I get the attachment back using that ID?

Here is the link to the doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/attachment-upload-api

Answer (score 0):

If you set is_reusable = true, then you can use the attachment to other recipients. But you can not edit the attachment or get the attachment back. Though, you can always send the attachment to yourself and view it from there.

Comment: Your idea is clever! :) 
I tried to send it to myself, but it didn't work. As it is a bot, I used its id to test it. I suppose that facebook knows who is a bot or not and block it. Here is the facebook response after sending a message to myself using the send API: 
400-Bad Request: {"error":{"message":"(#100) No matching user found","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":2018001,"fbtrace_id":"A7jBoNkQlZwb7aU1At41Ve8"}}

Answer (score 0):

You can get back the attachments using this API

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v16.0/message/attachments